# in Jquery, how can I make the content be hidden by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

in this code, which is from (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show). What should I add on the function so it stays hidden by default?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want it hidden by default you don't need `jquery`, you can simply add `hidden` to the tag you want to hide, e.g. `<button id="hide" hidden>Hide</button>`, then `show` it when you want it. To refer to your source [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp).

Comment: Looks like the OP already knows how to hide it **initially** using pure CSS.

Answer (score 5):

You can use pure CSS:

```
p {
    display: none
}
```

If you're looking for jQuery solution, then you can use **[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').hide();
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really do it with css, but this will do it with jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
    $("p").hide();  // this will hide it initially.
});
```

or css...

```
p {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
p {display:none}
```

Or jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').hide();
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
```